# Binding an Instance Matrix with an InputLayout

Tags: directx11, hlsl, matrix, instancing

If I want to bind an instance matrix to a vertex shader, how do I go about it?

For example, here is a super-simple VS input:

```
struct VS_IN {
    float4 Position : POSITION;
    row_major float4x4 WorldMat : INSTANCE_TRANSFORM;
};
```

How would the corresponding bindings look when creating the `ID3D11InputLayout`?

I figured it would be something akin to:

```
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC[] bindings = ...;
bindings[0] = { 
    "POSITION", // SemanticName
    0U, // SemanticIndex
    DXGI_FORMAT::DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, // Format
    0U, // InputSlot
    0U, // AlignedByteOffset
    D3D11_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION::D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, // InputSlotClass
    0U // InstanceDataStepRate
};
bindings[1] = { 
    "INSTANCE_TRANSFORM", // SemanticName
    0U, // SemanticIndex
    DXGI_FORMAT::DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, // Format
    1U, // InputSlot
    0U, // AlignedByteOffset
    D3D11_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION::D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, // InputSlotClass
    1U // InstanceDataStepRate
};
bindings[2] = { 
    "INSTANCE_TRANSFORM", // SemanticName
    0U, // SemanticIndex
    DXGI_FORMAT::DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, // Format
    2U, // InputSlot
    0U, // AlignedByteOffset
    D3D11_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION::D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, // InputSlotClass
    1U // InstanceDataStepRate
};
bindings[3] = { 
    "INSTANCE_TRANSFORM", // SemanticName
    0U, // SemanticIndex
    DXGI_FORMAT::DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, // Format
    3U, // InputSlot
    0U, // AlignedByteOffset
    D3D11_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION::D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, // InputSlotClass
    1U // InstanceDataStepRate
};
bindings[4] = { 
    "INSTANCE_TRANSFORM", // SemanticName
    0U, // SemanticIndex
    DXGI_FORMAT::DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, // Format
    4U, // InputSlot
    0U, // AlignedByteOffset
    D3D11_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION::D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, // InputSlotClass
    1U // InstanceDataStepRate
};
```

In the example above, I'm increasing the `InputSlot` value with each 'row' of the instance matrix, because I would expect that each row of the matrix would take up the next 128-bit input register.

However, in other examples I've seen on the internet, people seem to increase the `SemanticIndex` with each row instead. I thought that might because they declare the input as four `float4` fields instead of a matrix, but then I looked at [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/64298/direct3d11-and-sharpdx-how-to-pass-a-model-instances-world-matrix-as-an-input), and that doesn't seem to be the case.

Anyway, to cut to the point, **if I want to use `VS_IN` in the format I've provided, what is the correct way to lay out the input elements?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use same semantic for **SemanticName**, then you need to increase number for **SemanticIndex**.

I also see that you are increasing **InputSlot**. This may be correct or not depending on how your data is layed out. If you really have 4 vertex streams (vertex buffers) then it's fine, but I assume that your instance transform is stored in one vertex buffer. Then you need to set same stream number to **InputSlot** in every instance binding.

assume that:

```
stream_number = 4;
```

You'll also need to set this stream:

```
//  most probably offset_in_vertices will be 0 in your case
// vert_buf - contains your instrancing data
IASetVertexBuffers(stream_number, 1, &vert_buf, &stride, &offset_in_vertices);
```

Also while AlignedByteOffset is optional i suggest at least use D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT to specify that data go sequentially one after another.

so, setup code will look like this:

```
bindings[0] = { 
    // nothing changed
};
bindings[1] = { 
    "INSTANCE_TRANSFORM", // SemanticName
    0U, // SemanticIndex
    stream_number, // InputSlot
    0, // AlignedByteOffset: zero because start of a matrix
    // ...
};
bindings[2] = { 
   "INSTANCE_TRANSFORM", 
    1U, // SemanticIndex
    stream_number, // InputSlot
    D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, // or 16 (4 float32)    AlignedByteOffset
    // ...
};
bindings[3] = { 
    "INSTANCE_TRANSFORM", 
    2U, // SemanticIndex
    stream_number, // InputSlot
    D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, //or 32, AlignedByteOffset +4 float32
    // ...
};
bindings[4] = { 
    "INSTANCE_TRANSFORM", // SemanticName
    3U, // SemanticIndex
    stream_number, // InputSlot
    D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, // or 48 AlignedByteOffset +4 float32
    // ...
};
```

Then your vertex shader input structure will look like this:

```
struct VS_IN
{
    float4 Pos          : POSITION;
    float4 r0           : INSTANCE_TRANSFORM0;
    float4 r1           : INSTANCE_TRANSFORM1;
    float4 r2           : INSTANCE_TRANSFORM2;
    float4 r3           : INSTANCE_TRANSFORM3;
};
```

Or like this:

```
struct VS_IN
{
    float4 Pos                  : POSITION;
    row_major float4x4 inst_mat : INSTANCE_TRANSFORM;
};
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there no way to use an input `row_major float4x4 INSTANCE_TRANSFORM;`?

Comment: Yes there is. I've edited my answer to address your question. Have not tried it but it should work. Also do not forget about AlignedByteOffset, you should set correct value. E.g. for binding[2] it would be 16 (4 float32) for binding[1] = 32 and so on

Comment: See the InstancingFX11 sample on [MSDN Code Gallery](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Effects-11-Win32-Samples-cce82a4d)